# flask/jinja: creating a leaderboard out of an unordered dict object

Tags: python, dictionary, flask, jinja2

I have a flask endpoint function that passes a dictionary of ratings, positive points and negative points per user as follows:

```
leaderDict = {
    'users': {
        '<user1>': {
            'rating': 80.0,
            'positive': 32,
            'negative': 8
        },
        '<user2>': { ... }
    },
    'groups': { ... }
}
return render_template('leaderboard.html', **{"leaderDict": leaderDict})
```

What I want to be able to do, in Jinja, is to create a leaderboard out of the users, i.e. sort them by `rating` in declining order. If possible, I'd like to avoid recreating the data structure above on the flask side and do all of the parsing in Jinja. What's the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest you flatten the `user: {stats...}` dictionary, so the user appears as a futher key. You can do this with a list comprehension:

```
[dict([('user', k)] + list(v.items())) for k, v in a['users'].items()]
```

This will give you a list of entries that look like

```
{'user': '<user1>', 'negative': 8, 'positive': 32, 'rating': 80.0}
```

Add `sorted` to get it sorted:

```
sorted([dict([('user', k)] + list(v.items())) for k, v in a['users'].items()], key=lambda x: x['rating'])
```

and just iterate through the sorted list with `for ... in`. To sort reverse, use `reverse=True` in `sorted`

Comment: so the idea is that I would do this on the flask side and pass a `sorted` object to the template engine?

Comment: You should also be able to but it straight in the for in in the jinja template

Answer (score 1):

Jinja2 itself with its built-in filters can not do that. You either have to sort it in the view function or make a [custom filter](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/templating/#registering-filters).

Also note that a `dict` is never guaranteed to be in order; look at [`collections.OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) instead. Or better yet, make it a list like [mensi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17911832/220652) suggests.